# How do I get a list of namespaces on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to make a backup of all user data in the datastore.  My application is using the new namespace feature to provide multi tenanting on a per user basis (as per the example in the docs).

The bulk loader needs the namespace for each customer to download the data.  I don't keep a list of users, so I can't generate the namespaces.  Is there a method of detecting all the currently used namespaces?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since [SDK 1.4.0](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/metadataqueries.html#Namespace_Queries) you can use [Metadata Queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/metadataqueries.html#Namespace_Queries):

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import metadata

for ns in metadata.get_namespaces():
    print "namespace: '%s'" % ns.namespace_name
```

For NDB the import is slightly different:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import metadata
```

Comment: This no longer appears to work, and throws a KindError; @"c roald"'s answer below is the current way of achieving this.

Comment: As Brian points out, when using NDB there is no need to call .namespace_name since the string name is the return

Answer (score 6):

There is also now a get_namespaces() function:

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import metadata

namespaces = metadata.get_namespaces()
```

get_namespaces() returns a list of [Namespace](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/metadataentityclasses#The_Namespace_Class) objects.  The docs also note that "metadata queries that fetch information on namespaces, kinds, and properties are generally slow to execute."

Answer (score 4):

## Using `ndb`

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import metadata
all_namespaces = [ns for ns in metadata.get_namespaces()]
```

## Using `datastore`

Per [Datastore Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/metadataqueries#datastore-namespace-run-query-python):

```
query = client.query(kind='__namespace__')
query.keys_only()   
all_namespaces = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no API to get a list of namespaces. You must keep a record of the ones you use. I use a model specifically for this.