# How can I read all namespaces in one query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Unlike, [How do I get a list of namespaces on google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603276/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-namespaces-on-google-app-engine), this question asks, irrespective of knowing all the namespace names, is it possible to access data across all the namespaces with just one query.

---

I read the docs about namespaces, they are great for isolation of data, but I want to analyze some data from all the different namespaces.  Is it possible to run **one query** that encompasses all 1000 namespaces in my application; a namespace-independent query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get the data of all namespaces at once in a 'normal' query. you need to do that for each namespace separately.

but i believe you can do that with a mapreduce job.

Comment: Your wording, `'normal' query`, implies there might be a "non-normal" query that can accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603276/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-namespaces-on-google-app-engine) ("How do I get a list of namespaces on google app engine?").

Comment: i dont need namespace list. i need what is in namespaces

Comment: Original question's wording was ambiguous.

Comment: I think the wording is very clear and very distinct from the non-duplicate SO question you linked in.